# Is it possible to install the nb-javac jar file in NetBeans12.0 while offline?

Tags: java, netbeans

While my workstation is not technically offline, NetBeans is not allowed to communicate with the OSUOSL site to pull the nb-javac library. Oddly enough, I can browse to the site & download the JAR file manually, but the company firewall won't let NetBeans do it.

Is there a way to install the jar file without letting NetBeans access the site?

Comment: [1] Luckily for you, someone else has already faced this issue! See [How to install nb-javac offline into NetBeans 12?](https://www.mail-archive.com/users@netbeans.apache.org/msg07288.html). [2] As a related matter, note that unless you are using Java 8 you may not need _nb-javac_ at all - see comments from Geertjan Wielenga in the linked thread. [3] If that thread provides a solution for you then please post and accept your own answer here, since that helps the SO community.

Answer (score 0):

Of note, if you are stuck with JDK 8, you are stuck (AFAICT).  Try and get a more recent JDK and set the NetBeans default JDK to that (in the NetBeans /etc/netbeans.conf file).

If you do that, then as per the link @skomisa provided, you'll be good to go.